# APKtool FAIL - did not create apk

Tags: compilation, apktool

I use `apktool_2.5.0.jar b The_App_v0.1.apk` to decompile. I edit names in few files. Im not sure if it requires making a change to mainfest.xml but neither worked. Then I do `apktool_2.5.0.jar b The_App_v0.1` , all I see is a build\ folder is created in which I see some classes.dex file being made, no apk no dist folder ??

Then I cant even rename the folder or anything because it is used by some process.. the only process can be java which I dont see running.. This APKtool is GARBAGE

As it often happens, one day waste hours for nothing, the next day it works from first time.

Possible solution: `apktool_2.5.0.jar b "The_App_v0.1"`
... the quotes I read somewhere it cant recognize paths and doesnt know what it's doing

Comment: you are doing something wrong, please follow the steps for how to install apktool: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: `apktool_2.5.0.jar b "The_App_v0.1"` ... the quotes I read somewhere it cant recognize paths or maybe space or even dots and doesnt know what it's doing

compilation